# What is the opposite of :has() in jQuery to target the parent table having nested table

Tags: html, jquery

I have a nested table as below -

```
<table class="table parent">
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>TEXTA</td>
    <td>TEXTB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Has nested table below
        <table class="table nested">
        <tbody>
        <thead>
        <th>S.No.</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        </thead>
        <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>ABC</td>
        <td>PQR</td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
     </table>
     </td>
     </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>TEXTC</td>
    <td>TEXTD</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

If I want to add a background only to the td of nested table I could write something like -

```
$( "td" ).has( "table" ).css( "background-color", "red" );
```

but I want to select only parent td or td that does not have a nested table, how can I achieve this?

I am basically trying to change the width of ONLY those td that do NOT contain the nested table. So, in this case the width of only td containing TEXTA and TEXTC should change.

If there is a way to achieve this through CSS alone, please let me know.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/not/ ?

Comment: Of course, you could always add a class to all of them and then remove it from the ones you already know how to find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target the parent `td's` excluding the nested `table` using [Descendant Selector](https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) along with `.not(':has("table")')`

```
$(".parent > tbody > tr > td").not(':has("table")').css("background-color", "red");
```

**Live Demo:**

```js
$(".parent> tbody > tr > td").not(':has("table")').css("background-color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table parent">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>TEXTA</td>
      <td>TEXTB</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Has nested table below
        <table class="table nested">
          <tbody>
            <thead>
              <th>S.No.</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Contact</th>
            </thead>
            <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>ABC</td>
              <td>PQR</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>TEXTC</td>
      <td>TEXTD</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your solution !  I have a follow up question however. I have another scenario where I want TEXTA,TEXTC & "Has nested table below text" to be in red. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @ItykaBandta You are welcome - happy to help. So you want target parent table textA and textC as well as complete nested table to be in red ? is that what you meant ?

Comment: I mean target parent table textA and  text C and ONLY the text "has nested..." to be in red i.e. the nested table should remain unchanged.

Comment: @ItykaBandta Hmm a little trickly one. But let me try - its possible :)

Comment: @ItykaBandta something like this => https://jsfiddle.net/836fgu5q/2/

Comment: this can also be directly solved using .parent > tbody > tr > td:first-child{ } through CSS, no ? Which brings me back to square one ! :D  getting  the color is still ok. I am stuck at opacity and had even posted another question regarding it. So, TEXTA ,TEXTC and the text "Has nested..."(not TEXTB and TEXTD) have color red and 0.7opacity. The catch is since the nested table is also inside another <tr><td> of the target table, the opacity gets added to the entire child table as well which has been impossible for me to change !

Comment: @ItykaBandta Correct it can be done by just CSS - just as i said the td > nested table is a tricky one since your scenario is very different. The fiddle i have added above should resolve that issue as well and you can add opacity as well as color red. - using jQuery `eq` method you can add CSS to whatever td you want but the nested one will be tricky and you have to do a way around to achieve that one which i have done in my fiddle

Comment: I tried. But it also  affected the child table. Besides, I have more than 100 rows and child tables for random rows. It will be difficult by adding index for each nested row. Never mind, I'll change the structure and try a different approach. Thanks a lot for your effort and time ! :D The solution to the posted question did solve one scenario.

Comment: @ItykaBandta No problem. Yes i agree changing structure is definitely needed if there are more then 15 rows i believe. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Just invert it via `.not()`, feeding your `:has` pseudo selector to it.

```
$("td").not(':has("table")').css( "background-color", "red" );
```

Or even

```
$("td:not(:has(table))").css( "background-color", "red" );
```

Comment: this also picks the td of the nested table, which I don't want.